# Mean when computing correlation between samples of unequal size

Tags: time-series, correlation

This question is in some way similar to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/correlation-between-two-variables-of-unequal-size), but about another nuance.
I have two time series (update: stationary - with both mean and variance equal over time) with missing values in one of them, such as

- 1,2,3
- 1,Absent,3

(in reality I have many more observations). I want to compute their correlation, so I will not use the 2nd time-point in these data. But should I use it for computing the mean of the first series?

I think that including this point in computing the mean will lead to a more precise estimate of the population mean for the first variable, but don't know whether it is correct though.

Comment: What is a "suck point"?  A time with missing data?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm not very good in English.

Comment: That's ok.  Could you clarify your intentions, though?  I am wondering whether you are talking about computing the mean in the first time series for the purpose of developing a variance estimate (which will enter into the correlation calculation) or for some separate purpose.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/d/1/f/d1f59bcec903553cb6aa1d4d85866561.png - both for covariance and for variances of series.
My intent was to compute mean for first series only once and use it every time when it is needed in computation of correlation. However I need not save anything except Pearson correlation coefficient.

Comment: As @PeterFlom mentions below, using Pearson's $r_{xy}$ is probably not a good idea if you have true time series data. Could you provide more information about your data so someone can provide a more informed answer?

Comment: i think the interesting point of this question is that: here we have three or more series number, which can be denoted {{time_1, (1, 2, 3)}, {time_2, (missing, 2, 2)}, {time_3, (2, missing, 3)}}. So, the problem would be how can we calculate the correlation among these series values(e.g. time_1 vs time_2 and time_1 vs time_3). The problem is how can we derive a correlation value with homogeny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the first series $X_t$ and the second series $Y_t$ and denote the length of each series with $T$. You are asking if using all of the information from $X_t$ to calculate its mean in the computation of the correlation will make the estimate of the correlation more efficient. But you have to be precise about the exact way you want to calculate that correlation. Remember that:

$Cor(X_t, Y_t) = \frac{Cov(X_t, Y_t)}{\sqrt{Var(X_t) Var(Y_t)}}$,

where

$Cov(X_t, Y_t) = \frac{\sum (X_t - \bar{X}_t)(Y_t - \bar{Y}_t)}{T - 1}$,

$Var(X_t) = \frac{\sum (X_t - \bar{X}_t)^2}{T-1}$,

and

$Var(Y_t) = \frac{\sum (Y_t - \bar{Y}_t)^2}{T-1}$.

Now suppose half of the $Y_t$ values are missing. Then $Cov(X_t, Y_t)$ is calculated based on $T/2$ observations (even when $\bar{X}_t$ is calculated from all $T$ observations), so one would also divide by $T/2 - 1$ and not $T-1$. For $Var(X_t)$, one could use all $T$ observations (not only for calculating $\bar{X}_t$, but also for calculating the entire term, so one would still divide by $T-1$ here). And for $Var(Y_t)$, one only has $T/2$ observations, so one would divide by $T/2 - 1$.

I suppose this is what you mean. And you are not sure whether this estimator is more efficient than just doing pairwise deletion. If in doubt, you can always examine a question like this with a simulation study. Below is a simple example using R to simulate two time series, $X_t$ and $Y_t$, that are stationary and that are uncorrelated. I first calculate the observed correlation based on the full data. Then I induce random missingness on 50% of the $Y_t$ values. Then I calculate the correlation only based on the pairs of data points where $Y_t$ is not missing (i.e., pairwise deletion). And then I calculate the correlation as described above. I repeat this process many times and then calculate the mean correlation for each method (the three means should ideally be zero, indicating no bias in the estimators) and the standard deviation (indicating the efficiency of the estimators; smaller is obviously better).

```
iters <- 100000      ### number of iterations
nt <- 50             ### length of the series

ri <- matrix(NA, nrow=iters, ncol=3)
miss <- c(rep(1, nt/2), rep(0, nt/2))

for (i in 1:iters) {

    xt <- 0 + 0*(1:nt) + rnorm(nt)
    yt <- 0 + 0*(1:nt) + rnorm(nt)

    ri[i,1] <- cor(xt, yt)

    yt[sample(miss) == 1] <- NA
    not.miss <- !is.na(yt)

    ri[i,2] <- cor(xt[not.miss], yt[not.miss])

    mxt  <- mean(xt)
    myt  <- mean(yt[not.miss])
    num <- sum((xt[not.miss] - mxt) * (yt[not.miss] - myt)) / (sum(not.miss) - 1)
    den <- sqrt(sum((xt - mxt)^2)/(nt-1) * sum((yt[not.miss] - myt)^2)/(sum(not.miss)-1))

    ri[i,3] <-  num / den

}

round(apply(ri, 2, mean), 2)
round(apply(ri, 2, sd), 2)
```

If I run this, I get:

```
> round(apply(ri, 2, mean), 2)
[1] 0 0 0
> round(apply(ri, 2, sd), 2)
[1] 0.14 0.20 0.20
```

indicating no bias in the three estimators. The method that uses pairwise deletion is as efficient as the method that uses all of the information from $X_t$. So, apparently, you do not gain any efficiency in calculating the correlation by doing that.

Suppose there is actually a trend in time in both series. This will in fact induce a correlation between the two series. You can simulate this by replacing the respective lines with:

```
xt <- 0 + 0.15*(1:nt) + rnorm(nt)
yt <- 0 + 0.15*(1:nt) + rnorm(nt)
```

Rerunning the simulation yields:

```
> round(apply(ri, 2, mean), 2)
[1] 0.83 0.83 0.83
> round(apply(ri, 2, sd), 2)
[1] 0.03 0.05 0.10
```

so all three estimators give you the same answer (on average). But pairwise deletion is actually now more efficient than using all available information from $X_t$.

**Edit:** You can also induce a correlation between $X_t$ and $Y_t$ without a trend, for example, by replacing the respective lines with:

```
xt <- 0 + 0*(1:nt) + rnorm(nt)
yt <- 0 + 0*(1:nt) + 1.0*xt + rnorm(nt)
```

Rerunning the simulation yields:

```
> round(apply(ri, 2, mean), 2)
[1] 0.7 0.7 0.7
> round(apply(ri, 2, sd), 2)
[1] 0.07 0.11 0.15
```

and again, pairwise deletion is more efficient.

So, I would say: No, don't do this.

Comment: I really like the idea of running a simulation.  It has also been talked about in this forum about generating random numbers with a predefined correlation. It would be cool to do that, and then randomly select missing numbers and compare. (Like I think you did).  (I think you just used a correlation of zero, correct?)

Comment: I simulated the data under two conditions: first when the true correlation is zero and then when the true correlation is non-zero.

Comment: Sorry, you wrote " This will in fact induce a correlation between the two series. You can simulate this by replacing the respective lines with:"..I missed that somehow, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I'm bad at R - I understand it normally, but cannot write anything myself (previously I ported some code from R to Java). How can I modify it to test correlated series without trend? - Generate them as random int 1-10 (common for two series) + random value 0.0-1.0 (different for two series). (In Java this will take some minutes to write, I presume that it is easy modification to this code)

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to compute the correlation of two time-series: It's generally a bad idea, especially if the two series are not stationary.

But, if they were NOT time series, but just numbers, then I would NOT use the missing data: Correlation is between pairs of values. In both versions of the formula in your link, you have sums from 1 to n for both x and y - that is not n1 and n2 or some such, just n.  That implies the same thing that logic implies - don't use the missing points.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning stationarity, but I thought this to be a separate problem.

Comment: Re stationarity; if the two series have a trend, then they will correlate because both correlate with time.  For instance, manyu things about a country over time correlate with its population. 

Usually, though, this is not what people want: They usually want correlation "beyond" population; sometimes this can be expressed as a ratio.

Comment: Actually the application in that I needed such thing have not survived the prototype phase of the life-cycle. So now I have purely theoretical interest in this question. Lets assume that two series are stationary with both mean and variance equal over time.

Comment: @Peter I see your point that if series $X_t$ and $Y_t$ have some increasing or decreasing trend as a function of time, then this will induce a correlation between $X_t$ and $Y_t$. But I still don't see why that implies that correlating two time series is a bad idea, if what I am interested in is the correlation between the two series. Nothing about that correlation implies anything about causation. Could you elaborate why this is generally a bad idea?

Comment: Correlating time series is quite common in the financial sector, isn't it?

Comment: @IvanSopov I am not sure of the stationary case, but I think that the correlation is then better, although it still might be confounded by autocorrelation

Comment: @Wolfgang It's not really about causation. It's about a "false" correlation. I think it's the equivalent of a non-time series example: The more firemen who show up at a fire, the more damage is done (but it's really because bigger fires have more firemen and do more damage). In the time series case "size of fire" is "time".

Comment: @Peter Yes, "time" may be a third variable inducing a correlation between $X_t$ and $Y_t$. Sure. Anybody who calculates a correlation between two time series should be aware of that. But I don't see how this implies that calculating that correlation is generally a bad idea. If that were the case, then calculating any correlation would be generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Wolfgang Calculating correlations when you KNOW that there is likely a third variable that is causing both IS a bad idea.

Comment: @Peter That's why you could check for stationarity first or model the trend and look for a correlation in the residuals. Or look for a correlation between $X_t$ and lagged values of $Y_t$ (i.e., cross correlations). There are always things of increasing sophistication one can do. In any case, I still do not find anything unusual about this. But thanks for the feedback.